# how to use CRON expression to schedule a azure function to run for every one second during stock market time only?

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I have created a timer trigger Azure function to run for every one second, but I wanna run it only during the stock market time.
let's say 
from morning 9:15 AM to 3:30 PM and during this time it should run for every one second.
I'm running the Azurefunction for every second by using the following expression:
*/1 * * * * *

Comment: Keep in mind you may hit a snag due to public holidays etc.

Comment: yes, you are right, for that also I have to look out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you need create 3 CRON triggers for the time range for your specified time.

1. `*/1 15-59 9 * * *`,- Every second from 9:15AM to 10:00AM, ie, 9:15:00AM to 9:59:59AM
2. `*/1 0-59 10-14 * * *` - Every second from 10:00AM to 3:00PM, ie, 10:00:00AM to 2:59:59PM
3. `*/1 0-29 15 * * *` - Every second from 3:00PM to 5:30PM, ie, 3:00:00PM to 3:29:59PM

Comment: ok, but azure function provides only one interface for entering the CRON expression, how can I add three corn expressions

Comment: I mean you need create three triggers, it means three functions.

Comment: @saran k , if this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!